# Using an environment variable as a parameter

Tags: environment-variables

I've stored my BrowserStack details as environment details in my `bash_profile` file as `BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME` and `BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY`.

I want to pass the username and access key to an `npm` command when I'm kicking off my tests.

I can do it like this:

```
BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=<my-username> BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=<my-access-key> npm test config=@browserstack
```

but I want to do something like this instead:

```
BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=$BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=$BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY npm test config=@browserstack
```

but these fail. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Error thrown by Intern testing framework:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do the other way? What failures are you seeing? Are the variables empty? incorrect?

Comment: The errors are specific to the testing framework I'm attempting to use which suggest they aren't being passed correctly. See my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `npm` recognizes these two environment variable names, then it would be enough to `export` them in your shell's initialization file where you set them:

```
export BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=<my-username> 
export BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=<my-access-key>
```

Then you should be able to invoke `npm` from an interactive shell without mentioning them at all.

If `npm` is invoked by a script that is not inheriting you interactive environment, then set the variables in the above way in that script.

Comment: That worked - thanks! I think an important point here that I forgot was I didn't reload my terminal so the variables weren't even going to be there anyway

Comment: @Katana24 Ah, yes. Changing you shell's init files will only take effect for new shell sessions.